# Can an intrest problem be solved if the type is not specifed

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

For example, if we were just told that if we invest $400$ units now , and $250$ units 1 year from now, and are told it grows to $750$ units 2 years from now,  and we want to find the effective annual interest rate.

But we are not told if it is simple or compound, can it still be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Wikipedia (emphasis by me):

> The effective interest rate, effective annual interest rate, annual equivalent rate (AER) or simply effective rate is the interest rate on a loan or financial product restated from the nominal interest rate as an interest rate with **annual compound interest** payable in arrears.

Hence the initial investment of 400 units is worth $400\cdot q^2$ and the second investment $250\cdot q$ units (where $q=1+\frac{p}{100}$). So you are expectd to solve
$$ 400 q^2+250q=750$$
and from that find $p$.

Comment: Thanks but wont we need to know if the accumulation is (1+it) or (1+i)^t ?

Comment: so we do or do not?

Comment: @PersonaA See the emphasis on "annual compound interest".